# What is the effect of X509Chain ChainPolicy UrlRetrievalTimeout initialization?

Tags: c#, x509certificate

Using CSharp, if I do:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain ch =  new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain();
```

What is the effect of:

```
ch.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(4000);
```

?

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx

I would be initializing new instance of the TimeSpan structure to the specified number of ticks and a tick is equal to 100 nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx

This looks like I am setting a timeout to less than a millisecond to download certificate revocation lists. In practice, however, very large CRL files are being downloaded taking numerous seconds using such code.

So what does that line do exactly?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This looks like I am setting a timeout to less than a millisecond to download certificate revocation lists

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/security/system/security/cryptography/x509/x509chain.cs,383:

```
ChainPara.dwUrlRetrievalTimeout = (uint)Math.Floor(timeout.TotalMilliseconds);
```

So you effectively set it to "0", resulting in the OS default value. It's just a problem of how it has to round the value to send it down to Windows.

The value maps to `dwUrlRetrievalTimeout` on [CERT_CHAIN_PARA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377186(v=vs.85).aspx), which doesn't have a whole lot to say about how it's used (gap between downloads, a timeout during a message pump, et cetera).  But you could try `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)` (or some other small number) and see what you see.  1ms is not likely to exceed your TCP and HTTP connection times, so it will probably have the effect of computing the chain in `Offline` mode.

Comment: Thanks @bartonjs! That looks like "0" to me too. How do you associate that value to "default/infinite" please?

Comment: dwUrlRetrievalTimeout says `Optional time, in milliseconds, before revocation checking times out. This member is optional.` The "optionals" mean that a zero-value counts as wanting no timeout.

Comment: In practice @bartonjs, it looks like the default of 15 seconds is applied, so this zero "no timeout" setting would be ignored/overuled by the OS ?

Comment: I'd be willing to believe that the OS implements it as "0 means 15 seconds" instead of "0 means forever".  Since "15 seconds" is pretty close to "forever" in human/computer interaction I've never noticed the upper bound.